# Elasticsearch bulk data insertion

Tags: json, elasticsearch

In my node app i am using Elasticsearch as my backend process. I am trying to insert data from a json file but I got an error.

My json:

```
{"index":{"_index":"mfissample", "_type":"place_mfi", "_id": "1"}}
{"PAR" : 42.31,"Center":"xx","District":"yy","Country" : "vv","GLP" : 13073826.63,"State" : "zz","SSScore" :null, "location":"80.102134,12.897401"}
{"index":{"_index":"mfissample", "_type":"place_mfi", "_id": "2"}}
{"PAR" : 42.31,"Center" : "xx","District" : "yy","Country" : "zz","GLP" : 13073826.63,"State" : "vv","SSScore" :null,
"location":"80.102134,12.897401"}
```

My command:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_bulk' --data-binary @jsonbulk.json
```

The error:

```
{"error":"JsonParseException[Unexpected character (':' (code 58)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: [B@792c4b55; line: 1, column: 12]]","status":500}
```

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `\n` after `"SSScore" :null,` and before the `"location":"80.102134,12.897401"`.